# Error a la hora de mostrar datos con inner Join en php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Estoy realizando una consulta de 2 tablas con un inner join, esa consulta la hice y la ejecute directamente el mysql y me funciona bien, en el codigo php hice una busqueda instantanea pero me arroja un error en un dato de esa consulta,¿que podrá ser?
 agradezco su ayuda

Este es el codigo que tengo toda la consulta y el proceso, y en la base de datos tengo los nombre tal cual

```
    $tabla="";
    $query="SELECT * FROM inventario_productos ORDER BY idInventario";

    if (isset($_POST['alumnos'])){
      $q=$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['alumnos']);
// AQUI EMPIEZA LA CONSULTA CON INNER JOIN 
      $query="SELECT DISTINCT ip.idInventario,pr.nombre_producto,ip.cantidad_productos
    FROM entrada_productos et
    INNER JOIN producto pr ON et.Producto_idProductos1=pr.idProductos
    INNER JOIN inventario_productos ip ON et.Producto_idProductos1=ip.Entrada_Productos_Producto_idProductos1
       WHERE idInventario LIKE '%".$q."%'OR
      nombre_producto LIKE '%".$q."%' OR
      cantidad_productos LIKE '%".$q."%'";
    }
    $buscarProducto=$conn ->query($query);

      if($buscarProducto->num_rows > 0)
      {

        $tabla.='<table class="tablas">
          <thead id="letras">
             <tr class="interior">
               <th><a scope="col"> Id Inventario</a></td>
               <th><a scope="col"> Producto</a></td>
               <th><a scope="col"> cantidad Disponible</a></td>



             </tr>
          </thead>';

            while($fila=$buscarProducto->fetch_assoc())
            {
              $tabla.= '<tr id="ejemplos">
                  <td>'.$fila['idInventario'].'</td>
                  <td>'.$fila['nombre_producto'].' </td>
                  <td>'.$fila['cantidad_productos'].' </td>


              </tr> ';
            }
            $tabla.= '</table">';

            }else{
              $tabla="no se encontraron coincidencias con sus criterios de busqueda.";

            }

            echo $tabla;

     ?>
```

[image: imagen del dato erroneo]

Comment: cuantas tablas `nombre_producto` tienes?? si tienes mas de una puedes hacer un `pr.nombre_producto as "nombre_producto_pr"` o solo `pr.nombre_producto  "nombre_producto_pr"` para poder diferenciar de los otros!

Comment: solo tengo una tabla de nombre_producto

Comment: corre la query manual a ver que te devuelve! cuando son errores de querys puedes incluir un ejemplo desde [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6c585/1) colocas un ejemplo minimo de tus tablas con al menos 2 datos para cada 1 y compartes el link!  para que otros puedan ver la estructura y ayudarte mejor!

Comment: hago la consulta manual del query sin la condicion y me trae los datos bien , es decir consulto esto
SELECT DISTINCT ip.idInventario,pr.nombre_producto,ip.cantidad_productos FROM entrada_productos et INNER JOIN producto pr ON et.Producto_idProductos1=pr.idProductos INNER JOIN inventario_productos ip ON et.Producto_idProductos1=ip.Entrada_Productos_Producto_idProductos1 WHERE ip.idInventario LIKE '%495%'OR pr.nombre_producto LIKE '%495%' OR ip.cantidad_productos LIKE '%495%'

Comment: ya di solución, en el query inicial estaba llemando la tabla de productos nada mas, era necesario realizar el inner join hay tambien, de igual manera muchas gracias